# Iterate over a list of objects

Tags: c++, arduino

In JavaScript I might iterate over a set of objects containing data, like this:

```
const components = [
  {
    id: 1,
    pin: "A0",
    name: "light"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    pin: "A1",
    name: "sound"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    pin: "A0",
    name: "heat"
  },    
]

for (const component of components) {
  const value = analogRead(component.pin);
  console.log(`${component.name}:value`)
}
```

I often have a need to use code like this on the Arduino, but I'm not sure how I'd go about it.

NOTE: I'm not looking for an exact translation of this into C++; I want to know what the standard pattern is for achieving this is when using Arduino.

Comment: The  translation in C++ is 100% different from the translation in C.  What you show looks translatable to C++, more or less.  A similar job can be done in C, but it needs more work.  Which language are you really working with?

Comment: A very good reference is this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for . There is no only one standard way of doing this in C++ anyways. Google will help a lot on this

Comment: Not sure if this is right, but it would have been better if you posted this on the Arduino Forum

Comment: SO can't teach you a language from scratch. Your question is answered by any C++ book. Be aware that there are both different standard versions and flavours of implementations (e.g. the one for a small system like Arduino), so not every valid C++ solution may apply to your environment.

Comment: for those who want to answer: please keep in mind arduino platform doesn't have the c++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `C structure`. To do so you need to declare a structure first describing your object type.

```
struct component
{
  int id;
  char pin[10];
  char name[50];
};

component components[] = {
  {
   1,
   "A0",
   "light"},
  {
   2,
   "A1",
   "sound"},
  {
   1,
   "A0",
   "heat"}

};

int main ()
{

    int len = sizeof(components)/sizeof(components[0]);
    for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
    {
        printf("{ id: %d , pin: \"%s\" , name: \"%s\" }\n",components[i].id, components[i].pin, components[i].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{ id: 1 , pin: "A0" , name: "light" }
{ id: 2 , pin: "A1" , name: "sound" }
{ id: 1 , pin: "A0" , name: "heat" }
```

Comment: @Juraj It's ok  :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using modern C++ (11 or newer, which I understand arduino support), and your data is stored in an array you can simply do the following:

```
int values[5] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 }

for(auto const& value: values) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: arduino lib doesn't have the c++ std lib. There are no containers like `std::vector` available on arduino

Comment: Ah, you're right. Updated answer to refer to refer to simple arrays instead.